# Using Django filters as variables

Tags: django

I am wondering if we could use django filter as a variable where a python method formatting text can set the filter value which can be rendered by the template

The usual way filter works is like this

{{ html_text | safe }} or {{ plain_text | linebreaks }}

I want to set the values for filters 'safe'/'linebreaks' in a variable and render it like this

{{ text | filter_variable }}

Researched online, but couldn't figure it out, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Functions are first class objects in Python. You can pass them to other functions like they were variables. However, that's not going to help you at the template level in this case. You would have to write another template tag that accepted the filter method to apply (as a string) to the value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I second what Chris Pratt said, but I'd do it like this:

```
from django.template import defaultfilters

@register.filter
def apply_filter(value, filter):
    return getattr(defaultfilters, filter)(value)
```

that way it works for any filter.

Comment: That'll work as well. I chose to go with the explicit approach, though, to prevent unintended consequences. Some filters, themselves, require parameters, and wouldn't work with this custom filter. At the very least, though, you need to wrap the above in a `try...except` as it could blow up pretty readily if passed a bad filter or filter that requires more parameters than just `value`.

Comment: Fair enough. I guess it depends on how much you trust the template author... in my case, it's me, so I'm pretty trusting!

Comment: Never assume you will always be the one working with your code. Life is variable, so you should design for the unforeseen.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that, but you *can* create a custom filter that accepts a parameter:

```
from django.template import defaultfilters

@register.filter
def apply_filter(value, filter):
    if filter == 'safe':
       return defaultfilters.safe(value)
    if filter == 'linebreaks':
       return defaultfilters.linebreaks(value)
    else:
       # You might want to raise an exception here, but for example purposes
       # I'll just return the value unmodified
       return value
```

Then, in your template:

```
{{ text|apply_filter:filter_variable }}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response (and all others who replied), this is very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

This works if you have a few filters:

```
{% ifequal filter_variable 1 %}{{ text|safe }}{% endifequal %}
{% ifequal filter_variable 2 %}{{ text|linebreaks }}{% endifequal %}
{% ifequal filter_variable 3 %}{{ text|yourfilter }}{% endifequal %}
```